# Postgres - how to match columns for both null values

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am having postgres version 9.6. In one query I have requirement to match null values in where conditions.

```
select src.* from source src, report prs
where src.id=prs.id and coalesce(src.batch_id, 'null')=coalesce(prs.batch_id, 'null')
```

Means, it should return all rows where column batch_id is matched or null in both the tables , along with matching id. I could achieve this by applying  coalesce function but it will skip the index created in batch_id column.

Please suggest if there is any better way to do.

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.5 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`, which treats NULL as if it were an actual value:

```
SELECT src.*
FROM source src
JOIN report prs
  ON src.id = prs.id
 AND src.batch_id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM prs.batch_id
    ;
```

Also, since you are only interested in the `src` table's values, you could put the `prs` table reference in an `EXISTS (...)` condition. This will avoid generating duplicates in the result:

```
SELECT *
FROM source src
WHERE EXISTS ( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM report prs
    WHERE src.id = prs.id
    AND src.batch_id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM prs.batch_id
    )
    ;
```

NOTE: `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` is a Postgres extension to sql. It is not part of standard SQL.

Answer (score 0):

NULL mean that the value of the colum is unknown, so NULL is not equal to NULL

```
postgres=# SELECT 'True' result WHERE NULL = NULL;
 result 
--------
(0 rows)
```

you need to use is null in your where conditions

```
select src.* from source src, report prs
where src.id=prs.id and ( (src.batch_id=prs.batch_id) or ( src.batch_id is null and prs.batch_id is null))
```